# Place Id is returning null in New Place API Likelihood

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have implemented the new Place API and my nearest place list method is given below.

```
private fun getNearestPlaceList(placesClient: PlacesClient) {
        val placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.NAME)
        val request = FindCurrentPlaceRequest.builder(placeFields).build()
        placesClient.findCurrentPlace(request).addOnSuccessListener { response ->
            placeList.clear()
            for (placeLikelihood in response.placeLikelihoods) {
                if(!placeLikelihood.place.id.isNullOrEmpty() && !placeLikelihood.place.name.isNullOrEmpty()){
                    var placeModel = PlaceModel(placeName = placeLikelihood.place.name!!, placeId = placeLikelihood.place.id!!)
                    placeList.add(placeModel)
                }
            }
            setAdapter(placeList)
        }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            if (exception is ApiException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Place not found: " + exception.statusCode)
            }
        }
    }
```

In this placeLikelihood.place.id  is always returning null. Anyone know, how we can get the place id from likelihood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using

```
val placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.NAME)
```

You need to include `Place.Field.ID` if you want an ID returned.